# Sorting in elastic search using new java api

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am using the latest java API for communication with the elastic search server.

I require to search data in some sorted order.

```
       SortOptions sort = new SortOptions.Builder().field(f -> f.field("customer.keyword").order(SortOrder.Asc)).build();
    List<SortOptions> list = new ArrayList<SortOptions>();
    list.add(sort);

    SearchResponse<Order> response = elasticsearchClient.search(b -> b.index("order").size(100).sort(list)
            .query(q -> q.bool(bq -> bq
                    .filter(fb -> fb.range(r -> r.field("orderTime").
                                    gte(JsonData.of(timeStamp("01-01-2022-01-01-01")))
                                    .lte(JsonData.of(timeStamp("01-01-2022-01-01-10")))
                            )
                    )
                   // .must(query)
            )), Order.class);
```

I have written the
above code for getting search results in sorted order by customer.
I am getting the below error when I run the program.

```
Exception in thread "main" co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [search_phase_execution_exception] all shards failed
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:281)
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:147)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1487)
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1504)
at model.OrderDAO.fetchRecordsQuery(OrderDAO.java:128)
```

Code runs fine if I remove **.sort()** method.

My index is configured in the following format.

```
{
"order": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "customer": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "orderId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "orderTime": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "orderType": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "routing": {
                "allocation": {
                    "include": {
                        "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "provided_name": "order",
            "creation_date": "1652783550822",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "mrAj8ZT-SKqC43-UZAB-Jw",
            "version": {
                "created": "8010299"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please let me know what is wrong here also if possible please send me the correct syntax for using sort() in the new java API.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is type of `customer` field? is it `text` or `keyword` ? you can check using `GET order` command.

Comment: I am having document in below formet.         {
                "_index": "order",
                "_id": "S00_1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "orderId": "S00_1",
                    "orderTime": 1641020469000,
                    "customer": "Cust_0",
                    "orderType": "IN"
                }
            },         // customer is text

Comment: @SagarPatel Customer is text here.

Comment: You can not apply sort on text type of field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have confirmed in comment, `customer` is a text type field and this is the reason you are getting above error as sort can not apply on `text`type of field.

Your index should be configured like below for customer field to apply sort:

```json
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "customer": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have index mapping like above, you can use `customer.keyword` as field name for sorting and `customer` as field name for free text search.

Comment: @SagerPatel Thanks for the response, index configuration is in the same format, still its not working(Getting same exception). I have edited the question and added configuration details now

Comment: @VishalYadav Great !! Please mark as solution if it really helps you.